# Open JQuery Dialog Box with Multiple Buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'd like to have my Jquery dialog box open for several different buttons.  I have a facebook ui feed that is called on click (i'd like to have that inside the dialog box, but that's another story).  It is only opening for one button (the first button that appears in my html).  Here is the code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({autoOpen: false, resizable: false, draggable: false, height: 250, width: 500, modal: true, dialogCLass: 'main-dialog-class'});

  $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
                       $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog( "open" );

                       $.getJSON(
                                 "/like_artist.php", // The server URL
                                 { artist_id : $(this).data('artist_id') }, // Data you want to pass to the server.
                                 function(json) {

                                 var artist = json[1];

                                    var text = '';
                                    text = ' ' +  artist ;


                                    FB.ui({
                                    method: 'feed',
                                   // redirect_uri: '/index.php',
                                    link: 'WEBPAGE',
                                    name: '',
                                    caption: '',
                                    description: ''

                                    });


                                    $('#dialog-modal').text(text);

                                    alert(artist);
                                 }// The function to call on completion.
                                 );

        });

  });

</script>
```

The buttons:

```
<button type="button" id="opener" data-artist_id="3">Play My City</button>

<button type="button" id="opener" data-artist_id="4">Play My City</button>

<button type="button" id="opener" data-artist_id="2">Play My City</button>
```

etc...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's invalid to have multiple elements with the same ID in HTML. I'm guessing jQuery uses `document.getElementById()` to match `#opener`, which returns only one of those. Use `class='opener'` and `$('.opener')` instead.

Comment: when i use $('.opener') in place of $("#opener"), none of them open

Answer (score 0):

change all `id="opener"` to `class="opener"`

and then change your js `$( "#opener" ).click` to `$( ".opener" ).click`